# How can I debugging Ray framework?

Tags: ray

thanks for reply. I edit my question.
I want to distinguish whether the rpc_address is host or remote node, so I add some information in evet_stats.cc：

```
  const auto &rpc_address = CoreWorkerProcess::GetCoreWorker().GetRpcAddress();    
  RAY_LOG(INFO) << rpc_address.SerializeAsString() << "\n\n";
```

then add core_worker_lib in the ray_common's dependency in BUILD.bzael, but I find the

```
ERROR: /home/Ray/ray/BUILD.bazel:2028:11: in cc_library rule //:gcs_client_lib: cycle in dependency graph:
    //:ray_pkg
    //:cp_raylet
    //:raylet
    //:raylet_lib
.-> //:gcs_client_lib
|   //:gcs_service_rpc
|   //:pubsub_lib
|   //:pubsub_rpc
|   //:grpc_common_lib
|   //:ray_common
|   //:core_worker_lib
`-- //:gcs_client_lib
```

so， MY question is:

1. how can I use CoreWorkerProcess in event_stat.cc ?
2. when I change the code of event_stat.cc, I use " pip3 install -e . --verbose" to recompile project, but it is too slow. Is there a another way to fast recompile when altering the cpp code of ray ？

Comment: Could you share a code snippet? The debugging strategy you want will change on what you're trying to accomplish and the type of behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with this class to help. I'd recommend linking to this question in the [Ray Slack](https://www.ray.io/community), they can help you accomplish your goal.